# Widget is displayed in two places

Tags: functions, widgets, child-theme, register-sidebar

I want to add a widget below page content in my child theme. I used a function from here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes and the widget is displayed where I want:
[image]

but it is also displayed below page title (in div.entry-content).
[image]

In functions.php I have:

```
function twentytwentychild_after_post_widget( $content ) {
    if ( is_singular( array( 'page' ) ) && is_active_sidebar( 'after-post' ) && is_main_query() ) {
        dynamic_sidebar('after-post');
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'twentytwentychild_after_post_widget' );

register_sidebar( array(
    'id'          => 'after-post',
    'name'        => 'After Page Content Widget',
    'description' => __( 'description.', 'twentytwentychild' ),
) );
```

and in page-gallery.php before ending `</main>` I have:

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'after-post' ) ) : ?>
    <div class="footer-logo">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'after-post' ); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Why it is displayed on the top and how can I fix it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I used just normal function and it's ok.

```
function twentytwentychild_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Widget name', 'twentytwentychild' ),
        'id'            => 'after-post',
        'description'   => __( 'Widget desc.', 'twentytwentychild' ),
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget'  => '',
        'before_title'  => '',
        'after_title'   => '',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'twentytwentychild_widgets_init' );
```